# Normalization of an affine plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to normalize the affine plane curve $xy=0$?
Geometrically it should be the union of two seperate lines.
Actually, I have problem in finding the integrable closure of the ring $[,]/<>$

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Can you be more specific about what you need help with here? For instance, is the definition of normalization for a non-irreducible variety the issue? (If not, can you include your definition in the post?) Is the process of doing the calculations the issue? Being more specific will assist you in getting the help you need.

Comment: Actually, I have problem in finding the integrable closure of the ring $k[x,y]/<xy>$.

Comment: Please put this last comment in your post with an [edit] and include your definitions as well. (Not everyone reads the comments as well as they read the post, unfortunately.)

Comment: As far as I know, normalization only makes sense for integral schemes. This is not the case of your variety because $k[x,y]/\langle xy \rangle$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: @Don the usual first definition one encounters does assume this, but [there are ways around that](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035E). (The link is rather general; hopefully the OP adds their definition.)